# Make ShellScript run with custom CLI command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, 18.10

I have a shell script i use frequently to manually clear the dentries, inodes and page cache in my RAM: `ramflush.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " ██▀███   ▄▄▄       ███▄ ▄███▓   "
echo "▓██ ▒ ██▒▒████▄    ▓██▒▀█▀ ██▒  _____ "
echo "▓██ ░▄█ ▒▒██  ▀█▄  ▓██    ▓██░   |   | F"
echo "▒██▀▀█▄  ░██▄▄▄▄██ ▒██    ▒██    |   |  L "
echo "░██▓ ▒██▒ ▓█   ▓██▒▒██▒   ░██▒   |   |   U"
echo "░ ▒▓ ░▒▓░ ▒▒   ▓▒█░░ ▒░   ░  ░   \___|    S       _"
echo "  ░▒ ░ ▒░  ▒   ▒▒ ░░  ░      ░     ||  ____H__  -( (-"
echo "  ░░   ░   ░   ▒   ░      ░        |_'(-------)  '-'"
echo "   ░           ░  ░       ░           |       /"
echo "___________VERSION 1.0______________,-\__..__|_____"
echo " "
read -p "[*] Do you have a need to flush?:    " yn
case $yn in
   [Yy]* ) ;;
   [Nn]* ) echo "[X] Understood."; exit;;
       * ) echo "[X] No input detected. Exiting."; exit;;
 esac

echo " "
echo " <=== OPTIONS ===>"
echo " "
echo "1. Clear RAM Page Cache."
echo "2. Clear Dentries and Inodes."
echo "3. Clear Page Cache, Dentries and Inodes."
echo " "
read -p "[*] Choose what to flush:    " ans

case $ans in
   [1]* ) echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; echo "[*] Cache Cleared.";;
   [2]* ) echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; printf "[*]Dentries Cleared.\n[*]Inodes Cleared.\n";;
   [3]* ) echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; printf "[*]Page Cache Cleared\n[*]Dentries Cleared.\n[*]Inodes Cleared.\n";;
      * ) echo "[X] No input detected. Exiting."; exit;;

esac
```

However it gets tiresome constantly changing back to my home directory, then going in to a folder and calling the script. I also refuse to just do the commands manually because it defies the point to me having made the script.

Is there a way I can add this to my bash shell in order to be able to run the script from any directory simply by typing `ramflush` in order to call and run this script, similar to `nmap` or `ping`?

Would I have to add it to the package manager and how do I go about doing this?

Comment: In your ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.profile, whichever you use), add the script's directory to your PATH. Then, assuming the script file is executable, you can run it from anywhere.

Comment: Place it in the `~/bin` directory and add it to your path or place it in the `/usr/local/bin` folder which is already on your path

Comment: You might want to investigate the `select` bash command to present your menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop that script as `ramflush` without the `sh` extenion in two places:

1. `~/bin` or
2. `/usr/local/bin`,

for the first case add that path in `.bashrc` with the line `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` and the other is already in your path. Now you can simply type `ramflush`.

Comment: Thankyou for all the help. I've accepted @GeorgeUdosen 's answer as the best answer because of method two, which, from my perspective as a rookie to shell scripting - is the most universal method and easy to incorporate in a shell script to make this happen automatically. When I consulted that directory it appears that several tools have coined this method all ready.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way to do this, would be using an alias.

Add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias ramflush='/path/to/your/script/ramflush.sh'
```

Then open a new terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc` to reload your bash configuration.

You can now call `ramflush` anywhere in the terminal.

Comment: Requires the script is executable. Alternately `alias ramflush='bash /path/to/your/script/ramflush.sh'`